# Why does this generate compiler warning "Signed/Unsigned mismatch" only when compiled under x64?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider this code:

```
LARGE_INTEGER l;
size_t s;
if (s < l.QuadPart) return 1;
return 0;
```

When this is compiled under x64 it generates the `C4018` signed/unsigned mismatch compiler warning (Ignore the uninitialized local variable warning).

The warning is fine, since `QuadPart` is `LONGLONG` which is signed and `size_t` is unsigned.

But when I compile this under 32-bit there is no warning? How come? Under 32-bit `LONGLONG` is still signed and `size_t` is unsigned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On 32-bit `LONGLONG` is equivalent to `signed __int64` and `size_t` is equivalent to `unsigned int`. `unsigned int` has range that completely fits into `signed __int64` range, so the compiler widens (does integer promotion) `size_t` to `signed __int64` before the comparison and there's no warning.

On 64-bit `LONGLONG` is again equivalent to `signed __int64` but `size_t` is equivalent to `unsigned __int64`, so now `size_t` no longer fits into `LONGLONG` and the compiler can't perform any kind of promotion automatically, hence the warning.

Comment: I don't think the last statement is entirely correct. In the 64-bit case, the compiler does promote. It promotes `LONGLONG` (equiv. to `signed __int64`) to `size_t` (equiv. to `unsigned __int64`) just like it would have promoted `int` to `unsigned int`, had those been the variable types of `l` and `s`. And the compiler warns precisely because this promotion breaks the mathematically expected behavior of comparison (i.e. the negative values of `l` are treated as positive and fail to compare correctly with `s` in terms of math).